# The Fastest Queen Trap (Chess)

Tags: chess, optimization

This question is fairly simple, but simple doesn't mean easy (although for some people it probably is)

Find the fastest possible way to trap a queen in chess from the starting position.

Definition of a queen trap:

> 1. The queen must be attacked by an opposing piece.
> 2. The queen cannot make a legal move without being captured immediately after.

For example, the following was a queen trap achieved on White's seventh move:

[image]

(Note: This isn't even close to the fastest possible. It's just an example.)

Good luck!

Clarification: If the queen can trade itself for the opposing queen, or move to a place where it's defended and the only piece that can take it is the opposing queen, it's not trapped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one with three moves:

> 1. e4 g5
>  2. Qh5 e6
>  3. Qg6 h5

Comment: Whoops. Missed that. Added a clarification to the question. (By normal chess strategy, that isn't trapped because white can play something like Qg3).

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu Gotcha, edited!

Comment: Wow. This is actually _faster_ than my intended answer (which had it on white's fourth move.) +1 and accepted XD

Comment: Another one is rot13(1. p3 o6 2. Dn4 Ap6 3. Dkn7 On6).

Comment: Love it! +1 for you

Answer (score 4):

[Another solution](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=c3_b6_Qa4_Nc6_Qxa7_Ba6) with 3 moves as well, where the Queen is attacked twice.

> 1. c3 b6 2. Qa4 Nc6 3. Qxa7 Ba6

Answer (score 2):

Here is one on White's 4th, which you consider faster :)

> 1.Nf3 d6
>  2.Nd4 b6
>  3.h3 Nd7
>  4.Nc6

But still not as fast as Jafe's!

Here's an answer that probably doesn't meet what you mean either!
Black "traps" white's queen on move 4

> 1.c4 d6
>  2.b4 Bd7
>  3.h3 Ba4   (Note: at this point the queen isn't trapped)
>  4.g3 Qd7   (But at this point it is)

I'll keep looking :)

Comment: That's a valid answer. Not the fastest, but valid.